# How can I make a loop that checks if the chess pieces can hit eachother?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

My goal is to make sort of a chess game where you can place multiple towers or rooks, and the game is supposed to check if the chess pieces can hit each other or not, so far I have made the code you can see under,  but I am stuck on the loop that checks if one rook can hit another rook. I am quite confused on how to check this.  If anyone could help me or give me any hints on how to make the loop it would mean a lot! (Sorry for the norwegian variable names, if you need a translation or anything I will gladly help with it!!!)

Thanks in advance!!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="no">
 <head> 
    <title> Standardoppsett </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 
<style>
body{
  font-size: 25px;
}
.board {
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.firkant {
  height:calc(100% / 8);
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.hvit{
  background:white;
}
.svart{
  background:grey;
}
td:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer
}

</style>

<body>

<table class="board"></table>

<script>

let tableEl = document.querySelector("table")
let liste = []

for(let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  let trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  for(let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    let tdEl = document.createElement('td');
    tdEl.setAttribute("id","rute"+i+j)
    tdEl.addEventListener("click",plasserTårn)
    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
    // Bare på grunn av css
    tdEl.className = (i%2 === j%2) ? "hvit firkant" : "svart firkant";
    }
  tableEl.appendChild(trEl);
}

function plasserTårn(e){
  let trykketFirkant = e.target
  let plassertBrikke = {rad:trykketFirkant.id.substring(5,4), kolonne:trykketFirkant.id.substring(6,5)}
  liste.push(plassertBrikke)
  console.log(liste)
  console.log(plassertBrikke)
  for(let i = 0;i<liste.length;i++){
    let rekkefolgehusker = i 
    for (let k = rekkefolgehusker;k<liste.length;k++) {
      if(liste[i].rad == liste.rad[k]) {
      console.log("tårn blir slott");
      }
    }  
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but before pushing `plassertBrikke` to `liste`, you can do something like this to see if `plassertBrikke` can take any of the rooks already on the board.

```js
const piecesUpForGrabs = liste.filter(rook => {
  return plassertBrikke.rad === rook.rad || plassertBrikke.kolonne === rook.kolonne;
})

console.log('plassertBrikke can take these pieces:', piecesUpForGrabs);
```